# Issue with message output

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Hi I'm working on a bot that plays podcasts and streams on Discord in a voice channel. I have bumped in to a small issue when the bot is not in the voice channel and a member uses the command !stopstream it should ouput the message "No Stream Playing" however it keeps on outputting the message "Stopped! Thanks for tuning in" this should only output when the stream is stopped by using the !stopstream command which makes the bot leave the voice channel.

Here is the snippet I'm working with

```js
client.leaveVoiceChannel(message.member.voiceState.channelID);
message.channel.createMessage(`:stop_button: Stopped! Thanks for tuning in :wave:`);
if(client.leaveVoiceChanne == null)
    return message.channel.createMessage(`:exclamation: No Stream Playing.`);
```

Heres is how I'm using it in the code

```js
if (command == 'stopstream') {
     if (!message.member.voiceState.channelID)
         return message.channel.createMessage(`:exclamation: You have to join the voice channel to stop the stream.`);
     client.leaveVoiceChannel(message.member.voiceState.channelID);
     message.channel.createMessage(`:stop_button: Stopped! Thanks for tuning in :wave:`);
     if (client.leaveVoiceChanne == null)
         return message.channel.createMessage(`:exclamation: No Stream Playing.`);
 }
 if (command == 'streams') {
     message.channel.createMessage(stations);
 } else if (command == 'radio') {
     if (args == '')
         return message.channel.createMessage(`:exclamation: Please specify the radio stream example: **!radio <stream>** or use command **!streams** to see list. Use **!streamhelp** to show commands list.`);
     if (require('./stations.json')[args]) {
         if (!message.member.voiceState.channelID)
             return message.channel.createMessage(`:exclamation: You need to be in a voice channel to play that stream.`);
         client.joinVoiceChannel(message.member.voiceState.channelID).then(vc => {
             if (vc.playing) vc.stopPlaying();
             message.channel.createMessage(`:radio: You are listening to **${args}**. To change the stream use **!radio <stream>**`);
             vc.play(require('./stations.json')[args]);
         })
     } else {
         return message.channel.createMessage(`:frowning2: I cannot find a radio stream with that name. Make sure it has capitals and the correct spelling. Type **!streams** to see stream list.`);
     }
}
```

Seems I'm doing something wrong here, your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the "stream stopped" message before checking if a stream is playing. Move the check before that:

```js
if (!message.member.voiceState.channelID)
  return message.channel.createMessage(`:exclamation: You have to join the voice channel to stop the stream.`);
else if (client.leaveVoiceChanne == null)
  return message.channel.createMessage(`:exclamation: No Stream Playing.`);
client.leaveVoiceChannel(message.member.voiceState.channelID);
message.channel.createMessage(`:stop_button: Stopped! Thanks for tuning in :wave:`);
```

Comment: Still having no luck as this only seems to be now outputting "No Stream Playing" when then bot is streaming rather than actually stopping and outputting the message "Stopped! Thanks for tuning in :wave:" If I remove the line `else if (client.leaveVoiceChannel == null)
  return message.channel.createMessage(`:exclamation: No Stream Playing.`);` it works but when bot is out of the voice channel it obviously returns just "stopped! Thanks for tuning in :wave:" this is not I want it to do, But thank you for replying.

Comment: Is it as you have said in the comment above `else if (client.leaveVoiceChannel == null)`, or as I have just realised `else if (client.leaveVoiceChanne == null)` as in your original question and my response? If it is the typoed latter, then `client.leaveVoiceChanne` will be undefined and therefore equal to null.